# Get JSON String from rest service to js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, spring, rest

I am developing a function which return me json string from rest service to js. For this I develop a function on a button click which return me json string and  call rest service.
My js call click function is like -

```
 $scope.try = function () {
 alert("Hi")

  Restangular.one("tasks/try").get().then(function (data) {
  alert(data);
  });
 };
```

And my rest code for this call is -

```
@GET
@Path("/try")
@Timed
@Produces("application/json")
public String create() {

    return "{\"id\":1,\"name\":\"A green door\",\"price\":12.5}";
}
```

I want this json string in ui as it is but it return me this string as object.
I use angular js v1.3.16, jersey client v2.22.2 and spring.
Please provide me some solution.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: dont use alert inside the function it will show object instead alert use console.log(data) to print the data

Comment: I have tried this. The data is in Object from even I return it as json string

Comment: can u show as the response in console log

Comment: My console log is 'Object {id: 1, name: "A green door", price: 12.5, route: "tasks/try", reqParams: Object…}'

Comment: This give me error in console " SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1"

Comment: JSON.stringify(data)

Comment: This retrun me "{"id":1,"name":"A green door","price":12.5,"route":"tasks/try","reqParams":{"cacheBuster":1465198859217},"restangularized":true,"fromServer":true,"parentResource":null,"restangularCollection":false}" But I need only id,name,price which I passed from rest service

Comment: if possible please create a plunker or fiddle so that will be easy to see the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your response is restangularized. Please see [How to unrestangularize](https://github.com/mgonto/restangular#how-can-i-access-the-unrestangularized-element-as-well-as-the-restangularized-one)